# Convergence of the method :Newton-Raphson.(GATE)

Tags: convergence-divergence, newton-raphson

This question was asked in GATE exam and It's answer is 1. I could not understand this question.

Suppose that the Newton-Raphson method is applied to the equation $2x^2+1-e^{x^2}=0$  with an initial approximation $x_0$ sufficiently close to zero. Then, for the root $x= 0$, the order of
convergence of the method is equal to _________(Fill in the blanks)

Comment: Who is supposed to make a guess ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : From the title, it looks like either of Mssrs. Newton or Raphson.  $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
Appu:  What have you tried?  What are you thinking is the right strategy for this problem?  What do you understand/not understand about the problem?

Comment: @Appu maybe this is not the apropiate site for asking about your homeworks. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a simple zero Newton's method converges quadratically. But not so if we have a zero of higher order. Assume that we want to find the zero of the function $f(x):=x^2$ using this method. We then obtain the recursion
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-{f(x_n)\over f'(x_n)}=x_n-{x_n^2\over 2x_n}={x_n\over2}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
This shows that at each step the distance to the zero of $f$ is halved, in other words: We only have *linear convergence*.

In the example at hand the situation is similar: We are told to find the zero of
$$g(x):=1+2x^2-e^{x^2}=1+2x^2-\left(1+x^2+{x^4\over2}+?x^6\right)=x^2-{x^4\over2}+?x^6\ .$$
Newton tells us to look at the auxiliary function
$$\psi(x):=x-{g(x)\over g'(x)}=x-{x^2-x^4/2+?x^6\over 2x-2x^3+?x^5}={x^2-3x^4/2+?x^6\over 2x(1-x^2+?x^4)}\ .$$
It follows that
$$\psi(x)={x\over2}\left(1-{x^2\over2}+?x^4\right)\ ,$$
so that at each step the distance to the zero is essentially halved when $x_n\to0$.

(In the above each question mark represents a certain power series $a_0+a_1x+a_2 x^2+\ldots$ convergent in a neighborhood of $0$.)